# Using anonymous event in function

Tags: c#, events, lambda, anonymous-function

```
public static void OnAutoScrollToEndChanged(DependencyObject s, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    /* ... */

    var scrollToEndHandler = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler((sender, args) => // 수정
    {
        if (listBox.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            object lastItem = listBox.Items[listBox.Items.Count - 1];

            listBoxItems.MoveCurrentTo(lastItem);
            listBox.ScrollIntoView(lastItem);
        }
    });

    if (isAutoScroll)
    {
        source.CollectionChanged += scrollToEndHandler; // A
    }
    else
    {
        source.CollectionChanged -= scrollToEndHandler; //B
    }
}
```

> https://michlg.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/listbox-automatically-scroll-to-bottom/

This code is referenced by upper URL.

A(scrollToEndHandler) and B(scrollToEndHandler) are in a function.

When 'AutoScrollToEndProperty' is changed, 'OnAutoScrollToEndChanged' will be called all the time.

I wondering whether These are same reference. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "A(scrollToEndHandler) and B(scrollToEndHandler) are in function." Could you clarify the question please?

Comment: @JonSkeet I think OP means this handler is defined inside the function body.

Comment: @DannyChen: Well yes, it is - but then what is meant by "I wondering whether These are same reference"? (The edit doesn't really help...)

Comment: *...across calls* maybe?

Comment: Okay, I *think* I see what the OP means...

Comment: Sorry! I studying English, So not well..
I want to know that A and B are same reference address. @JonSkeet

Comment: Do you mean "Is the value of `scrollToEndHandler` the same reference across multiple method calls?" I *think* that's what you're after, but it's a significantly clearer way of expressing it. (See my answer, which assumes that *is* what you meant.)

Answer (score 4):

If your question is basically, "Does unsubscription actually work here?" the answer is C# compiler implementation-specific, theoretically.

On a practical basis, the body of the lambda expression doesn't capture any local variables, but does capture `this` (by referring to `listBox`)... so I'd expect the compiler to generate an instance method containing the body of the code in the lambda expression.

If the method is called multiple times on the same target (i.e. `this` refers to the same object), I'd expect `scrollToEndHandler` to be a distinct but equal delegate each time - in other words, it would create a new delegate object in each call (which it probably *wouldn't* if the lambda expression didn't capture anything, and could be implemented as a static method and the delegate cached)... but the event subscription/unsubscription will still work because the delegates are equal (referring to the same target for the same method).

If the lambda expression referred to any local variables in the method, then event handling *wouldn't* work, because the compiler would capture those local variables via a separate nested class containing the relevant variables and a method for the delegate code, and each method invocation of `OnAutoScrollToEndChanged` would create a new instance of that nested class, leading to unequal delegates.

As I say though, that's all implementation-specific... it would be better to just move that code into a separate instance method, to make it clearer that it would work.